# BS4 table issue

Tags: html, angular

Hello I have tried to make a table that has expenses, amount kai action but I have a problem with the alignment. I tried to correct it through the width but unfortunately it did not work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        
    <body>
    <a routerLink="/addexpense">Add Expense</a>
    
    <div class="div1">
    <label for="keyword">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" 
    id="keyword"
    [(ngModel)]="filters.keyword"
    name="keyword"
    (input)="listExpenses()">
    </div>
    <div class = "container">
      
    <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered" >
       <tr>
         <th>Expense</th>
         <th>Amount</th>
         <th>Actions</th>
       </tr>
         
         
         
       <div *ngFor ="let expense of expenses">
        <tr> 
         <td>{{expense.expense}}</td>
         <td>{{expense.amount | currency: '&euro;'}}</td>
         <td> <a routerLink ="/editexpense/{{expense.id}}">Edit</a>
              <button *ngIf="expense.id" (click)="deleteExpense(expense.id!)">Delete</button>
         </td>  
        </tr>
       </div>
      </table>
     </div>
    </body>
```

result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not to bind `*ngFor` to `<div>` element.

Instead, you need to **bind `*ngFor` to `<tr>` element** and **remove `<div>` element** from the `<table>`.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Expense</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
    <td>{{expense.expense}}</td>
    <td>{{expense.amount | currency: '&euro;'}}</td>
    <td> <a routerLink="/editexpense/{{expense.id}}">Edit</a>
      <button *ngIf="expense.id" (click)="deleteExpense(expense.id!)">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cbxlej?file=src/app/app.component.html)